# the size of DDR3 RAM

Tags: memory

What is the biggest size DDR3 Memory Module today and biggest size of one chip in the module, and what is the chip organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung has a 32GB DIMM.

[This article](http://www.engadget.com/2009/06/18/samsung-debuts-first-32gb-ddr3-memory-module/) has a good description of the organization:

> the module itself is made up of 72 of those 4Gb memory chips, which are lined up in rows of nine quad-die packaged 16Gb DDR3s mounted on each side of the circuit board

Notice little 'b' = bits and big 'B' = bytes.

They have since shrunk the die size from 50nm to 40nm to 30nm which decreases the voltage and increases the throughput as stated in [this article](http://www.geek.com/articles/chips/samsung-starts-producing-30nm-32gb-ddr3-modules-20110531/):

> In performance terms, a 30nm 32GB DIMM running at 1.35 volts can achieve 1,866Mbps. The same 40nm 32GB DIMM requires 1.5 volts and only achieves 1,333Mbps.

They mention 20nm chips being available by the end of 2011, but I haven't seen an article stating they've packaged them into a DIMM yet.

Comment: Thnx a lot for the answer. But i dont understand why they say the size of the DIMM is 32GB, although according to the calculation with given parameters: 74 *4/8 = 36 (GB), am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: (72 * 4) / 9 = 32GB. Extra bit for parity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_parity